# Retrieve information from txt file to use as a variable in a python file

Tags: python, string, variables, text, extract

I am dealing with a problem where I want to extract stock names from a text file to use in multiple python scripts, so that if I add one or more stocks I dont have to alter all the python files.

My stocks.txt file is:

```
AAPL
GOOG
TSLA
```

If I import this the script saves A.txt, A.txt, P.txt, L.txt, G.txt etc.

It takes every letter as seperate. How can I change my code so that it takes AAPL, GOOG and TSLA?

Thank you!

My reduced script:

```
import urllib2
import time
import datetime
import os

filePath = os.path.abspath('stocks.txt')
openFile = open(filePath, 'r')
stockToPull = str(openFile.read())

def pullData(stock):
    try:
        saveFileLine = "today_data\\" +stock+".txt"

    except Exception, e:
        print 'main loop', str(e)

while True:
    for eachStock in stockToPull:
        pullData(eachStock)
```

Comment: The simple change is `str(openFile.read())` becomes `openFile.readlines()`,

Comment: Don't forget to `openFile.close()` afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is the line

```
stockToPull = str(openFile.read())
```

This is taking the entire contents of `openFile` as a single string.  Therefore when you iterate through `stockToPull` you are iterating through a string, which produces a series of single letters

Instead use

```
stockToPull = openFile.readlines()
```

`file.readlines()` produces a list of a all lines in the file.  If the file is particularly large, or you don't want the intermediate variable, you can also loop directly through the file as:

```
while True:
    for eachStock in openFile:
         pullData(eachStock)
```

Some other unrelated critiques:

- As you have your code written, the `while True:` will create an infinite loop
- Data from files often has extra `\n` or space characters, consider adding `pullData(eachStock.strip())` to remove these
- As pointed out in a comment, you neglect to close the file.  You can either add an explicit close statement or use a context manager such as shown below.
- This may be just because of your stripped down code, but typical convention is to put function definitions before any executed code (excluding imports)
- This one is very minor, I've always seen it as `except Exception as e:`, which is thing is more readable
- Use `os.path.join()` to create file path strings.  Alternatively here you could use a raw string to prevent needing `\\`

Putting it all together

```
import urllib2
import time
import datetime
import os

def pullData(stock):
    try:
        saveFileLine = os.path.join("today_data", stock+".txt")   
    except Exception as e:
        print 'main loop', str(e)

filePath = os.path.abspath('stocks.txt')
with open(filePath, 'r') as openFile:
    for eachStock in openFile:
         pullData(eachStock.strip())
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm :)

Comment: @Rico, glad to hear it.  Since this answer solved your problem, please mark it as "accepted"

Comment: Done! Thank you :)